# Application error django blog app with heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I deployed a Django blog app to Heroku and the build was successful but on opening the app I got a page saying application error, it said to check the logs but I don't get the message.

Here's the log

```
2021-04-27T15:41:49.301926+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=campusstory.herokuapp.com request_id=c5396159-b7e0-4ada-8764-54d40add0bc2 fwd="102.89.3.201" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-27T15:41:49.674072+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=campusstory.herokuapp.com request_id=22a9b86c-9b7a-4851-8ff1-7c0c8c733a44 fwd="102.89.2.205" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-27T15:47:31.201263+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=campusstory.herokuapp.com request_id=477c9fb1-4b53-4bb8-9fc2-1f4e66604ff0 fwd="102.89.2.205" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-27T15:47:31.619852+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=campusstory.herokuapp.com request_id=3ef7ae48-18cb-4979-8bce-ef80dc4e021f fwd="102.89.3.44" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-27T15:47:33.950102+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=campusstory.herokuapp.com request_id=4abaafe0-8bd6-4d0c-a7fb-c0524fc4ca00 fwd="102.89.3.201" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-27T15:47:34.389228+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=campusstory.herokuapp.com request_id=3b3953cf-8f47-4de9-ba88-4da2c4e14249 fwd="102.89.2.205" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

A common error is not setting up your Procfile correctly. You can read more about it [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile). For the sake of example here is what your Procfile should look like

```
web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi --log-file -
```

Of course, make sure you have gunicorn installed in your Django proyect.

Now, if that is already in your project the problem may be that you do not have any dynnos running. A fix can be done by letting Heroku know with:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Here you can learn about [dyno configurations](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-configurations) and [deploying](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) your app

Comment: I got a  Couldn't find that process type (web). error

Comment: @Amazing-GraceUmoren Note that "myproject" in "myproject.wsgi" refers to the directory where your wsgi file is. Also, make sure you have a requirements.txt file with all the packages you have installed (gunicorn should be in there)

Comment: You can find more information about configuring Django in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration

Answer (score 0):

I'm a relative newcomer to Django, and I've recently been through the process of deploying to Heroku for the first time, which I didn't find super straightforward. Here are some things you need to do to make it work:

Install (in your virtual environment) the packages `psycopg2`, `django-heroku`, and `gunicorn`.

Create a `requirements.txt` at the top level of your local project folder by running `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

As pointed out in another answer, create a `Procfile` in your project directory containing the line `web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi --log-file -`

In your `settings.py` file, add `import django_heroku` and (at the bottom is okay) `django_heroku.settings(locals())`.